# Hitting time level and Bernoullis

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables, on
the same probability space, with parameter $1/2$, and let $\tau_n$ be the hitting time of level n by the partial sums, i.e. $\tau_n = \inf\{ k \big| \sum_{l=1}^k X_l = n\}$ Show that $n^{-1} \tau_n$ a.s. converges to 2.

ge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the law of large numbers.

$\tau_1$ is the index of the first $X_n$ which takes the value $1$, it has a geometric distribution.

$P(\tau_1=n)=P(X_1=\cdots=X_{n-1}=0,X_n=1) = \frac{1}{2^n}$, $E(\tau_1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \frac{1}{2^n} = 2$.

$\tau_n$ is a sum of $n$ independent copies of $\tau_1$, since to go from $0$ to $n$ you have to go first from $0$ to $1$, then from $1$ to $2$, and so on.

So, by the strong law of large numbers, $\tau_n/n\to E(\tau_1)=2$ almost surely.